# Linq problem: The expression of type 'System.String[]' is not a sequence

Tags: c#, linq, subsonic3

I thought I would throw an omni-search on my data.

So I made a function that returns any match on a string.

ex.

```
var results = (from d in db.MyData
where new string[]{ d.DataField1.ToString(), d.DataField2.ToString(), ... }.Contains(searchTerm)
select d);
```

But when I try to iterate over it I get `The expression of type 'System.String[]' is not a sequence.`

```
//blows up on first iteration
foreach(var v in results)
{...}
```

Can anyone give me a few pointers?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem is the `.Contains`, since the linq query won't give you a String[] in any case.

Comment: @recursive, he's explicitly creating a `string[]`, then calling `Contains` on that.  I don't think that's the problem.  And `string[]` does implement `IEnumerable<string>`, which provides access to `Enumerable.Contains`.

Comment: can you set context.Log = Console.Out; and take a look to the underlying query?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran that query in Linqpad and it ran, but not how you wanted.  It didn't do a LIKE against each field inside %'s, it did an IN against the set, which would only match if the data matched exactly.  Can you just write it out?

```
var results = (from d in db.MyData
  where d.DataField1.Contains(searchTerm) || d.DataField2.Contains(searchTerm)
  select d);
```

Comment: <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 <3 Good call, an omni search should not need an exact match. Thanks!